# Memory consumption API

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a way to get total heap consumption (and consumption of specific datatypes) in app runtime (GHC)? I'm writing profiler for my interpreter, so I can't use standard ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the total heap consumption and other stats via [`getGCStats`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/GHC-Stats.html#v:getGCStats) in module GHC.Stats, at least if you run your program with `+RTS -T`.